# pretty print virustotal API output with jq

Tags: json, curl, jq

I am trying to format the json output from the VirusTotal API in way that gives me all the relevant data in one overview. The VirusTotal API can be called through curl like this (you need to regiser first for the API key, the data passed is the hash of the file you suspect of being malware):

```
curl --silent https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/report -F apikey=$VTAPI -F resource=b2349998571ab733d4ee0ca8a82afa614527aec75679569a91940631851c3d2b
```

and the output is in json. So jq is the way forward to make this human readable:

```
curl --silent https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/report -F apikey=$VTAPI -F resource=b2349998571ab733d4ee0ca8a82afa614527aec75679569a91940631851c3d2b | jq "."
```

This will give something like below (11 engines detect the file as being malware,
check the permalink URL the view the details on the VT website):

```
{
  "scans": {
    "Bkav": {
      "detected": false,
      "version": "1.3.0.9899",
      "result": null,
      "update": "20200418"
    },
    "TotalDefense": {
      "detected": false,
... etc.
  "resource": "b2349998571ab733d4ee0ca8a82afa614527aec75679569a91940631851c3d2b",
  "response_code": 1,
  "scan_date": "2020-04-18 12:36:44",
  "permalink": "https://www.virustotal.com/file/b2349998571ab733d4ee0ca8a82afa614527aec75679569a91940631851c3d2b/analysis/1587213404/",
  "verbose_msg": "Scan finished, information embedded",
  "total": 61,
  "positives": 11,
  "sha256": "b2349998571ab733d4ee0ca8a82afa614527aec75679569a91940631851c3d2b",
  "md5": "a860ff8b038de1ab70706163f4adf955"
}
```

I put the complete json VT output on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/raw/36S3JCSZ)

What I would like, is to show only the records with detected == true
and format them in a way that all the relevant info is visible in one single overview,
without needing to scroll back.
I could make a perl script to do that, but since jq is so powerfull, i am hoping that it's also possible to formate everything in there?
Ideally it would look like this:

```
MicroWorld-eScan        14.0.409.0      20200418        Trojan.GenericKD.42992262
McAfee                  6.0.6.653       20200417        Artemis!A860FF8B038D
...
"scan_id": "b2349998571ab733d4ee0ca8a82afa614527aec75679569a91940631851c3d2b-1587213404",
"sha1": "155f680dfc91b0f90976c0892bb883f7a360e041",
"resource": "b2349998571ab733d4ee0ca8a82afa614527aec75679569a91940631851c3d2b",
"response_code": 1,
"scan_date": "2020-04-18 12:36:44",
"permalink": "https://www.virustotal.com/file/b2349998571ab733d4ee0ca8a82afa614527aec75679569a91940631851c3d2b/analysis/1587213404/",
"verbose_msg": "Scan finished, information embedded",
"total": 61,
"positives": 11,
"sha256": "b2349998571ab733d4ee0ca8a82afa614527aec75679569a91940631851c3d2b",
"md5": "a860ff8b038de1ab70706163f4adf955"
```

I tried some stuff with jq, but i am not getting very far :(

```
% jq '.scans[] | "\(.detected)" + "   " + .result' vt-json.txt | grep -v false
"true   Trojan.GenericKD.42992262"
"true   Artemis!A860FF8B038D"
"true   Trojan.Generic.D2900286"
"true   Trojan.GenericKD.42992262"
"true   Trojan.PDF.Generic.O!c"
"true   Trojan.GenericKD.42992262"
"true   Trojan.GenericKD.42992262 (B)"
"true   Artemis"
"true   malware (ai score=86)"
"true   Trojan.GenericKD.42992262"
"true   Trojan.GenericKD.42992262"
```

and

```
jq '. | select( .scans[].detected == true ) | .result ' vt-json.txt
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
```

thanks in advance for any help.
Ewald...

Comment: Include a [mcve].

Comment: Welcome on SO. I agree with oguz, please try to make an effort on the example in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get an output close to what you showed but in valid json with this.

```
jq '
    .scans |= with_entries(
        select(.value.detected)
        | .value |= .version + " / " + .update + " / " + .result
    )
' vt-json.txt
```

---

```
{
  "scans": {
    "MicroWorld-eScan": "14.0.409.0 / 20200418 / Trojan.GenericKD.42992262",
    "McAfee": "6.0.6.653 / 20200417 / Artemis!A860FF8B038D",
    "Arcabit": "1.0.0.870 / 20200418 / Trojan.Generic.D2900286",
    "BitDefender": "7.2 / 20200418 / Trojan.GenericKD.42992262",
    "AegisLab": "4.2 / 20200418 / Trojan.PDF.Generic.O!c",
    "Ad-Aware": "3.0.5.370 / 20200418 / Trojan.GenericKD.42992262",
    "Emsisoft": "2018.12.0.1641 / 20200418 / Trojan.GenericKD.42992262 (B)",
    "McAfee-GW-Edition": "v2017.3010 / 20200418 / Artemis",
    "MAX": "2019.9.16.1 / 20200418 / malware (ai score=86)",
    "ALYac": "1.1.1.5 / 20200418 / Trojan.GenericKD.42992262",
    "GData": "A:25.25440B:26.18419 / 20200418 / Trojan.GenericKD.42992262"
  },
  "scan_id": "b2349998571ab733d4ee0ca8a82afa614527aec75679569a91940631851c3d2b-1587213404",
  "sha1": "155f680dfc91b0f90976c0892bb883f7a360e041",
  "resource": "b2349998571ab733d4ee0ca8a82afa614527aec75679569a91940631851c3d2b",
  "response_code": 1,
  "scan_date": "2020-04-18 12:36:44",
  "permalink": "https://www.virustotal.com/file/b2349998571ab733d4ee0ca8a82afa614527aec75679569a91940631851c3d2b/analysis/1587213404/",
  "verbose_msg": "Scan finished, information embedded",
  "total": 61,
  "positives": 11,
  "sha256": "b2349998571ab733d4ee0ca8a82afa614527aec75679569a91940631851c3d2b",
  "md5": "a860ff8b038de1ab70706163f4adf955"
}
```

The filter `select(.value.detected)` removes tools which have not detected anything, while the filter `.version + " / " + .update + " / " + .result` formats the output in case of positive detection.

Comment: That is exactly what i meant. I am very impressed with your jq skills, thanks for helping me out!

Comment: I made a zsh alias with for easy use:
`vtcheck () {
 myhash=$(sha256.pl $1 )
 curl --silent https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/report -F apikey=$VTAPI -F resource=$myhash | jq '.scans |= with_entries(select(.value.detected) | .value |= .version + " / " + .update + " / " + .result)'
}`

Comment: Glad the output suits you even if the format is not exactly what you had in mind initially. And thanks for the flowers (although SO has plenty of skilled users with low reputation you know). I still have a lot to learn about effective use of jq but I'm already very happy to have spent some time practicing this powerful and rewarding (and fun !) tool.